# Autowire freemarker is not working with junit test in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I have added freemarker template inside spring boot. I did autowiring as follows:

```
@Autowired
private Configuration freemarkerConfig;
```

After auto wiring, my server is working fine but when I am trying to execute any test case, it fails with error

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'freemarkerConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'freemarker.template.Configuration' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I tried adding `@SpringBootTest` but it's not working.

Comment: do you resolve it?

Comment: Not able to resolve yet..Still searching solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating your test case with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, so the `@Autowired private Configuration freemarkerConfig` gets initialized by Spring.

See [EnableAutoConfiguration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html).